# C - Putting command line arguments int an array

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to make put command line arguments by the user into an array but I am unsure how to approach it.

For example say I ran my program like this.

./program 1,2,3,4,5

How would I store 1 2 3 4 5 without the commas, and allow it to be passed to other functions to be used. I'm sure this has to do with using argv.

Comment: If you get rid of the commas, then `argv` *is* the array.

Comment: Command line arguments are not comma-separated the way function arguments are in C. They are space-separated. As the above mentions, if you space-separated your values, `argv` is an array of `char *` types (strings). Is there a reason you need to pass the values in a single, comma-separated string?